# Change JSON property name if Jackson has decided to use ObjectIdentity for output

Tags: java, json, jackson

Given a class

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class User {
  public int id;
  public User other;
}
```

If Jackson matches a previously seen `User` object, it will use the `ObjectIdGenerator` to output the id instead of the actual object.

An example output:

```
{
  "id": 1257,
  "other" : {
    "id": 411,
    "other": 1257   
  }  
}
```

However, I'd like to use a different property name if the object id is triggered, so the output looks like

```
{
  "id": 1257,
  "other" : {
    "id": 411,
    "otherRef": 1257   
  }  
}
```

Will a custom serializer achieve this? I can find plenty of examples where the property value is changed by a custom serializer, but none where the property name is changed based on the property value.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `@JsonGetter` to do this. Mark the field with `@JsonIgnore` and then create a method with the name `getOtherRef` marked with `@JsonGetter`.

Comment: That won't work. Then you'd end up with {
  "id": 1257,
  "otherRef" : {
    "id": 411,
    "otherRef": 1257   
  }  
}

Comment: Oh, you're right. I didn't process the nesting of `User`. Using a custom serializer might be tricky as you'd have to keep track of the users that the serializer found, and then reinitialize the context when you start at the top. Maybe you need one custom serializer for the `User` class and then another one for the field (or another getter). But I'm not seeing how they would work together and be thread safe, etc.